# Способ образования слов

Tags: словообразование

Каким способом образовано слово ПОТЕМКИ?
А НЕПРЕКРАЩАЮЩИЕСЯ (дожди)?

Answer (score 2):

Потёмки - приставочно-суффиксальный; непрекращающиеся - приставочный.

Comment: потемки - потемнеть... почему не суффиксальный?

Answer (score -1):

От какого слова произошло выражение *в потёмках*? Какой здесь способ словообразования?

Comment: Здесь бы надо ответить, но в ответ — два вопроса. Не хорошо.